# Setting up ASP settings using Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: c#, iis, asp-classic

Is it possible to configure `asp` settings for a given `location` using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` package?

I'd like to programatically add the following section to a local IIS `applicationHost.config` file.

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <location path="Default Web Site/myAppPath">
        <system.webServer>
            <asp appAllowClientDebug="true" appAllowDebugging="true" enableParentPaths="true" scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

</configuration>
```

I cannot find any way, as this section doesn't belong to any site or application which are possible to maintain using this package.

If not, are there any more feature-rich alternatives to `Microsoft.Web.Administration`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. There's even a wizard that may help you to create such scripts from the IIS Manager GUI if you have [Administration Pack](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/administration-pack) installed on your server.

IIS Manager > Sites > Default Web Site > **myAppPath** > Configuration Editor

Screenhots were taken for Default Web Site but the steps are the same for a virtual application like yours.

[image: IIS Configuration Editor]

Select section (`system.webServer/asp`) and configuration file (`ApplicationHost.config <location path="Default Web Site/myAppPath">`) and make the changes.

[image]

After making the changes **do not click Apply**, just click the **Generate Script**. This will open a dialog with some scripts ready to use to make changes programmatically.

[image: Script Diaog]

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {

        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

            ConfigurationSection aspSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/asp", "Default Web Site");
            aspSection["appAllowClientDebug"] = true;
            aspSection["appAllowDebugging"] = true;
            aspSection["enableParentPaths"] = true;
            aspSection["scriptErrorSentToBrowser"] = true;

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```